# Win10 installed on external hard drive: can I use game capture?

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-hard-drive, gaming, video-capture

I am running Windows 10 on my Mac Mini using Bootstrap, except I've installed Windows on an external hard drive rather than the mac itself.

Originally I had Windows installed on my Mac, and could use gaming 'capture' feature just fine.

However since I've installed Windows on an external, Windows now tells me:

> your pc doesn't meet the hardware requirements for captures

Is there a way around this?

Comment: No;  I am honestly shocked you were able to boot Windows in the first place, performance must be abysmal, due to the bandwidth of the external drive

Comment: It can be quite slow to start up but apart from that it seems fine to be honest, I didn't even realise it was a thing until I noticed tutorials on how to do it on YouTube